# What is the exact reputation required to vote in a moderator election?

Tags: support, election

Here are my queries..

- **What is the exact number of reputation required to vote in a moderator election?**

  Is it like I should have the same amount of reputation on all the sites where I am a member. Or if I have sufficient reputation on one of the Stack Exchange sites, is that
  sufficient to cast votes?
- **What are the badges that one should possess in order to cast votes?**

  Just like the candidates who are competing for the moderator election, should the voters need some basic badges in order to participate in the election?

Comment: [check this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135778/why-is-150-reputation-needed-to-vote-in-elections)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka - This had not answered my query completely. Even before it is answered completely, please kindly don't close my question, moderators. Please..

Comment: @PraveenVinny Please _don't_ remove the automatically inserted duplicate link, it will be automatically removed _if_ the question is re-opened. Also, your question is _fully answered_ in the duplicate, no reason for it to be re-opened.

Comment: @Yannis - Sorry! I didn't know that. Expecting for the vote to `reopen` my query and I expect an answer to my SO question.

Comment: i assume its far more than 1076 .. you need to got atleast 3000 with some required badge

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need 150 reputation on the site where the election is running (including the association bonus, if you have it). Your reputation on other sites doesn't matter.

No badges are required for voting in the election. I don't think there should be either. We want as many community members as possible to vote and reducing the number of eligible voters doesn't seem to make much sense. The reputation requirement is there to ensure some participation and investment in the site so that elections can't be adversely affected by bored outsiders, but requiring badges on top of that would be overkill.

See more information about the elections [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work).